# Boto Ec2 and elastic IP's

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto

Is it possible to associate an an elastic IP address with an ec2 instance using python boto? I'm trying to automate a deploy. I searched the api documentation in the ec2 section and found nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't know what documentation you were looking at, but it's in there:

http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.address.Address.associate

> ```
> associate(instance_id=None, network_interface_id=None, private_ip_address=None, allow_reassociation=False, dry_run=False)
> ```
>
> Associate this Elastic IP address with a currently running instance. :see: boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection.associate_address()

Comment: Thanks, must have missed it.

Comment: [Answers should not depend entirely on external links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259). We're trying to build a stable long-term resource, so answers need to directly contain enough information to be worth keeping even if the links are broken. Please edit your question to include the essential information or it may be deleted. (Don't just copy and paste: plagiarized content will also be deleted.) Thanks!