# possible to programmatically assign itself an elastic ip?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

Is it possible for a bash script running inside an ec2 ubuntu instance to assign itself a vacant elastic ip address identified by eipalloc-abcd99481?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which has an `aws ec2 associate-address` command:

```
aws ec2 associate-address --instance-id i-0b263919b6498b123 --allocation-id eipalloc-abcd99481
```

See: [AWS CLI `associate-address` documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/associate-address.html)

Comment: This works if the instance is launched with and currently has a public IP from the pool (non-EIP) which will automatically be replaced by the EIP.  Without a public IP, the instance can't connect to the EC2 API im order to submit the request.

Comment: Ah! So true! The Elastic IP Address will *replace* the existing Public IP Address.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using this command: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/opsworks/associate-elastic-ip.html

You could also make a Python script: [Boto Ec2 and elastic IP's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20448428/boto-ec2-and-elastic-ips)

Also, don't forget that you need the correct permissions (Manage level) in order to execute this command.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be [preferable to include the essential parts of the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) here, and provide the link for reference.